# how to set preview-latex left indentation on formulas?

Tags: emacs, preview, live-preview

Preview-latex is good to leave some left indentation on formulas. When the window is small, however, the left indentation on preview is a bit excessive, is there any way to change the amount of indentation (as red circled in the following figure)?

Many thanks!
[image: the figure]

I tried to set the variable `preview-preserve-indentation` to `nil`, but does not seem to help.

---

### Update

Using the `exam` option,

```
% \documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ad}{ad}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)
\]
\[
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(x)\bigg|_{a}^{b}=F(b)-F(a)
\]
\[
e^{X}Ye^{-X}=e^{\ad_{X}}Y=Y+[X,Y]+\frac{1}{2!}[X,[X,Y]]+\frac{1}{3!}[X,[X,[X,Y]]]+\dots
\]
\[
\hat{D}(\alpha)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\abs{\alpha}^{2}}e^{+\alpha\hat{a}^{\dagger}}e^{-\alpha^{*}\hat{a}}=e^{+\frac{1}{2}\abs{\alpha}^{2}}e^{-\alpha^{*}\hat{a}}e^{+\alpha\hat{a}^{\dagger}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the `article` option
[image]

Using the `[fleqn]{exam}` option
[image]

overall, it is not so troublesome if I choose `\documentclass{article}` instead of `\documentclass{exam}`. `fleqn` works, but changes the pdf output all togather, what if I just want to have less indentation for preview-latex inside emacs?

Comment: The global option `fleqn` to the class might help, but this would affect the final document as well.

Comment: Do you mind providing a MWE?  Actually, I cannot reproduce such a long preview snippet, even without the `fleqn` option.

Comment: @giordano, I have added a MWE and several snapshots. For details see the update. Many thanks!

Comment: Ok, I confirm I cannot reproduce.  Do you use a custom scale factor for preview snippets?

Comment: @giordano, oh excuse me, I did use `(set-default 'preview-scale-function 1.5)`.

Comment: That's all: if you scale the snippet you magnify also the left white space `:-)`  A value between 1.2 and 1.3 gives me better results.

Comment: @giordano, thanks! btw, does the variable `preview-preserve-indentation` actually have anything to do with the indentation?

Comment: I don't know, trying setting it to `nil` doesn't seem to have any apparent effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the value of the scale factor by setting [`preview-scale-function`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html#index-preview_002dscale_002dfunction) to 1.5 with

```lisp
(set-default 'preview-scale-function 1.5)
```

In this way you magnify the snippet and the left white space.  You can get better results using values between 1.2 and 1.25.