# Redefine commands / Remove left spacing for equations in LaTeX Preview (also in Emacs AUCTeX)

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, auctex, preview

When I run

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[active, tightpage, displaymath]{preview}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
1+2 = 3
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I get the following result
[image]

I checked this question ["Crop equations with preview package"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13981/crop-equations-with-preview-package) but the solutions provided there, using external script or replace equations all inline, don't work for me because that image snippet will be used for Emacs auctex preview that automatically inserts "`\usepackage[options...]{preview}`" to the original tex document, generate equation snippets, then overlay them on the equation strings making the editing like more WYSIWYG-ish.

Anyway, Emacs auctex variable `preview-default-preamble` enables me to insert some custom strings to the preamble when it generates the preview images, so I was looking for something like

```
\renewcommand{\begin{equation*}}{\begin{math}\displaystyle}
\renewcommand{\end{equation*}}{\end{math}}
```

to be inserted to the preamble when I run `preview-document`.

But those naively written `\renewcommand` commands don't work of course. I know that I can use `\renewcommand` or even `\def` or `\let` to redefine macros, but how can I do it for the macro with certain arguments? More directly,

> What should I put in the preamble so that whenever the compiler sees `\begin{equation*}` it replaces it with `\begin{math}\displaymath` and run it?

PS. This may look like an XY question, but I'm also interested in finding the solution because I have something else that I could do with that. :-)

Comment: You may find it useful to read up on `\renewenvironment` etc and understand how LaTeX environments work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for ShreevatsaR's comment, I found it and it was simple! I don't know why I was so obsessed with macros, but I just put

```
\renewenvironment{equation*}{\begin{math}\displaystyle}{\end{math}}
```

and it worked perfect. (I could not put `$` in place of `\begin{math}` and `\end` though but that's not a big issue and is understandable why it doesn't work.)

I'll also edit the title because this thing with preview with that spacing has been an minor annoyance for quite a long time for me (cf. [how to set preview-latex left indentation on formulas?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193008/how-to-set-preview-latex-left-indentation-on-formulas)).